# iOS ViewController buttons dissappears after pushing to a new controller and coming back again using Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, macos, swift, xcode6

This question may have been asked here before, but it's in obj C and I tried countless ways with no success. So, I have a viewcontroller with an array of buttons which are added one at a time when the user clicks an add button. The problem is i have a navigation controller and whenever i go to another page and comes back to this viewcontroller page, the buttons are gone. Help would be much appreciated as I am new to Swift and thanks in advance!

Here are my codes:
Adding Buttons

```
func addStartingButtons()
{


    for lockers in arrayOfLockers
    {


        let addLockerbtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 250, y: buttonY + 70, width: 120, height: 30))
        buttonY = buttonY + 80  // we are going to space these UIButtons 50px apart

        addLockerbtn.layer.cornerRadius = 10  // get some fancy pantsy rounding
        addLockerbtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        addLockerbtn.setTitle("Add New+", forState: UIControlState.Normal) // We are going to use the item name as the Button Title here.
        addLockerbtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        addLockerbtn.addTarget(self, action: "ButtonPressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        self.view.addSubview(addLockerbtn)  // myView in this case is the view you want these buttons added
    }


}//end of addStartingButtons Func


func ButtonPressed(sender:UIButton!)
{

    let image = UIImage(named: "lock.png") as UIImage!




    if number<7
    {
            if number == 1
            {

                self.btn1.hidden = false
                btn1.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
                btn1.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
                btn1lbl.text? = "Locker\(number)"
                btn1.layer.cornerRadius = 10




            }

            else if number == 2
            {

                self.btn2.hidden = false
                btn2.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
                btn2.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
                btn2lbl.text? = "Locker\(number)"
                btn2.layer.cornerRadius = 10


            }

            else if number == 3
            {
                self.btn3.hidden = false
                btn3.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
                btn3.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
                btn3lbl.text? = "Locker\(number)"
                btn3.layer.cornerRadius = 10



            }


            else if number == 4
            {
                self.btn4.hidden = false
                btn4.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
                btn4.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
                btn4lbl.text? = "Locker\(number)"
                btn4.layer.cornerRadius = 10



            }

            else if number == 5
            {
                self.btn5.hidden = false
                btn5.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
                btn5.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
                btn5lbl.text? = "Locker\(number)"
                btn5.layer.cornerRadius = 10



            }

            else if number == 6
            {
                self.btn6.hidden = false
                btn6.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
                btn6.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
                btn6lbl.text? = "Locker\(number)"
                btn6.layer.cornerRadius = 10

            }



        number++
```

And this is for navigationController:

```
let splitViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UISplitViewController
    let navigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[splitViewController.viewControllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController
    navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem()
    splitViewController.delegate = self
    return true
```

Comment: where u cal this func  `func addStartingButtons()`?

Comment: It's called inside the viewDidLoad() func

Comment: try replace function call to `viewWillAppear()`

Comment: It didn't work, previously i had set the buttons to be hidden and when i replace the func call to viewWillAppear(), the buttons are hidden but can be  clicked and it solved my problem but thats not what i really want... thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Anyone? I am vexed about this matter